# How to create nested array using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

My goal is to convert an array into a nested multidimensional array.

input: `[1,2,3,4,5...n]`

output: `[1,[2,[3,[4,[5,[n]]]]]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add your code. what does not work?

Comment: [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) should be useful for that.

Comment: This is a fun exercise and it's sad the OP missed an opportunity to solve it on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the first item and the rest and check the length of the rest and return either a new array with item an the result of the recursive call or only the item in an array.

```js
const
    nest = ([item, ...rest]) => rest.length
        ? [item, nest(rest)]
        : [item];

console.log(nest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I really like this solution. kudos

Answer (score 2):

You can have a function like this:

```js
function nest (arr) {
    if(arr.length === 1) return arr;
    return [arr[0], nest(arr.slice(1, 0))]
}
```

and call it like this `nest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

The same code in ES6:

```js
let nest = ([first, ...arr]) => arr.length ? [first, nest(arr)] : [first]
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `reverse()` and `forEach()` function to achieve this.

```js
var i = [1,2,3,4,5];
var result = [];
var current = [];
i.reverse().forEach((num) => {
    current.unshift(num);
    result = current;
    current = [current];
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```